# How to randomly show DIV from array using php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to randomly show the DIV from an array using PHP. on every reload div should be shuffled.

```
$divs = array('<div><a href="<?=base_url()?>colors"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1566106887/color_codes.png" class="img-responsive color-code"></a></div>','<div><a href="<?=base_url()?>colors"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1566025433/Genuine_Reviews.png" class="img-responsive color-code"></a></div>');
$randKey = array_rand($divs,2);
echo $divs[$randKeys[1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shuffle()` in php (Here is the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)).

Example :

```
$arr  = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'];
shuffle($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
        $divs = array(
            '<div><a href="<?=base_url()?>colors"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1566106887/color_codes.png" class="img-responsive color-code"></a></div>',
            '<div><a href="<?=base_url()?>colors"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1566025433/Genuine_Reviews.png" class="img-responsive color-code"></a></div>'
        );
        $count = count($divs) - 1;
        $randKey = rand(0, $count);
        echo $divs[$randKey];
```